# how do you convert data frame column to int in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert data type to inter in python

when I do

```
df1.dtypes
```

I get this:

```
max          object
```

I need to convert df1['max'] to int

when I do this:

```
df1["max"]=df1['max'].astype(int)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '312.72857666015625'
```

I tried to round the max before converting like this:

```
df1[['max']] = df1[['max']].apply(lambda x: pd.Series.round(x, 2))
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: ("can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'", u'occurred at index max')
```

is there an easy way to do this in pyton pandas?

Comment: Try first to convert it to str, then to int: `df1["max"]=df1['max'].astype(str).astype(int)`

Comment: I still get this error: ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '312.72857666015625'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to convert the `str` to `int`

```
s.astype(float).astype(int)
Out[213]: 
0    312
dtype: int32
```